# LINQ: why this query works in query syntax but not in method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query

```
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };

var query =
    from     n in names
    where    n.Contains ("a")   // Filter elements
    orderby  n.Length           // Sort elements
    select   n.ToUpper();       // Translate each element (project)

foreach(var item in query)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

works perfectly, gives the result `JAY MARY HARRY` as expected.

But when I run this

```
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };

var query2 = names.Where(n=> n.Contains("a")).OrderBy(n=>n.Length).Select(n=>n.ToUpper);

foreach(var item in query2)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

I get this message `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

I tried running this too

```
var query2 = names.Where(n=> n.Contains("a")).OrderBy(n=>n.Length).Select<string, string>(n=>n.ToUpper);
```

It says `Cannot convert method group 'ToUpper' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method? Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<string,string>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.`

I don't know what's happening? Can any one tell me why the query syntax is working fine method syntax is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parentheses after `ToUpper`:

```
var query2 = names
    .Where(n=> n.Contains("a"))
    .OrderBy(n=>n.Length)
    .Select(n=>n.ToUpper() /* <<== HERE */);
```

Comment: Bulls*it! That's so terrible! Thanks man! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to call ToUpper as a method (with parentheses):

```
var query2 = names.Where(n=> n.Contains("a")).OrderBy(n=>n.Length).Select(n=>n.ToUpper());
```