# Populating TextBox field

Tags: c#, string, forms, textbox

I'm building a simple form app for an assignment. I want to output a modified version of a string variable "newSentence" with methods but I'm not sure how. Here's my code snippet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sentence = textBox2.Text;
        string extract = textBox1.Text;
        bool b;
        string newSentence = sentence.Replace(extract, " ");

        if (b = sentence.Contains(extract))
        {   
            textBox3.Text = newSentence.ToUpper; // here id like to get newSentence in
            textBox4.Text = newSentence.Length;  //uppercase but Im stuck on how to 
                                                 //convert the types  
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what specific errors you get when compiling this and what you have tried to resolve those?

Comment: errors: cannot convert method group "ToUpper" to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method? and Cannot implicitly convert type int to string

Comment: Duplicate of [LINQ: why this query works in query syntax but not in method syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813776/linq-why-this-query-works-in-query-syntax-but-not-in-method-syntax).

Answer (score 3):

**1)** ToUpper is a method not property.

```
textBox3.Text = newSentence.ToUpper;
```

to

```
textBox3.Text = newSentence.ToUpper();
```

**2)** `Length` returns int, convert it to string

```
textBox4.Text = newSentence.Length;
```

to

```
textBox4.Text = newSentence.Length.ToString();
```

**3**)

```
if (sentence.Contains(extract))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** You are using `ToUpper` as property

**Solution 1:** You need to use `String.ToUpper()` as method but not as property.

From MSDN : [String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Returns a copy of this string converted to uppercase.

Try This:

```
  textBox3.Text = newSentence.ToUpper();
```

**Problem 2 :** you can set only string to the Text property of the TextBox control

**Solution 2:** convert the `newentence.Length` to `String` before assigning it to the `TextBox` `Text` Property.

Try This:

```
textBox4.Text = newSentence.Length.ToString();
```

**Suggestion :** you dont need to assign the return value to another boolean variable.
so you can simply check the retur value of the return value of the `Contains()` method.

```
if (sentence.Contains(extract))
{

//code here

}
```

**Complete Code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sentence = textBox2.Text;
    string extract = textBox1.Text;        
    string newSentence = sentence.Replace(extract, " ");

    if ( sentence.Contains(extract))
    {   
        textBox3.Text = newSentence.ToUpper(); 
        textBox4.Text = newSentence.Length.ToString();  

    }
 }
```

Comment: @Downvoter: could you please give me any suggestions to improve this post?